# Why is this code giving inaccurate result?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print sum of all prime numbers between 2 and a given number N that would be input by the user. so if the input number is 10 the output should be 17. my code below though it works but not providing accurate results. what seems to be the issue here?

```
N=int(input())
sum_prime=0`enter code here`
#Calculate primes between 2 to N
for value in range(2,N+1):
    if value>1:
        for i in range(2,value//2+1):
            if value%i==0:
                break
            else:
                sum_prime+=value          
 print(sum_prime)
```

Comment: `for value in range(2,N+1):`  then `if value>1:`   ... how do you think that value will be _ever_ not bigger one?

Comment: did you simply print and see if you _really_ only get primes by your algorythm?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you currently get?

Comment: Your code "as is" gives a SyntaxError - after fixing that an IndentationError .. do you really need help with those?

Comment: @PatrickArtner- yes value>1 doesnt need to be there.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your error. You add numbers to `sum_prime` even though the loops to check if it really a prime aren't finished. You have to move the addition out of the loop, like this for instance:

```
N=int(input())
sum_prime=0
#Calculate primes between 2 to N
for value in range(2,N+1):
  is_prime = True # note that I have added a new variable
  for i in range(2,value//2+1):
    if value%i==0:
      is_prime = False
      break
  if is_prime:
    sum_prime += value # the addition is now out of the inner loop
print(sum_prime)
```

If I input `10`, it correctly outputs:

```
17
```